# UITableView order of willDisplay and didEndDisplaying

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've encountered very odd behaviour with two delegate methods

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("will display \(indexPath.section) - \(indexPath.row)")
        addInputRules(tableView, cell, indexPath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("did end display \(indexPath.section) - \(indexPath.row)")

        removeInputRules(tableView, cell, indexPath)
    }
```

I am adding and removing input validation rules to table view cells while scrolling. 
It works perfectly. But when I do section reload with

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet([indexPath.section]), with: .automatic)
```

There are willDisplay and didEndDisplaying delegate methods called but in inappropriate order!

There is willDisplay and after it didEndDisplaying

```
will display 0 - 0
will display 0 - 1
will display 0 - 2
will display 0 - 3
will display 0 - 4
will display 0 - 5
did end display 0 - 0
did end display 0 - 1
did end display 0 - 2
did end display 0 - 3
did end display 0 - 4
did end display 0 - 5
did end display 0 - 0
did end display 0 - 1
did end display 0 - 2
did end display 0 - 3
did end display 0 - 4
did end display 0 - 5
```

What is causing my validation rules to be removed!

Comment: Cocoa is event-driven. You should not care, in `didEndDisplaying`, whether a corresponding `willDisplay` was given previously. Just code around it.

Comment: They should be called if cell appear and diseappear in table View but here it doesn't correspond to what is seen on screen. I need to replace my code with reloadData() to have correct will display/ end display. I am registering/unregistering validation rules for input fields in currently visible cells so order is important

Comment: Well, you can file a bug report with Apple. But meanwhile one must just live with reality. You don't get to say when something "should be called". There are situations where `viewWillAppear` is called without `viewDidAppear` being called. It seems wrong but that's life. This is similar. You just have to code around it, as I said.